# How to print every variable from biggest to smallest in python

Tags: python

I'm working on a zif's law project in python. I wrote this code:

```
import os
my_file = open("words.txt", "r")
content = my_file.read()
w = content.split()
my_file.close()

def split(a):
    return[char for char in a]

x = 0
for i in range(len(w)):
    w[x] = w[x].lower()
    s = split(w[x])

    y = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[y] == "." or s[y] == s[y] == "," or s[y] == "'" or s[y] == "0" or s[y] == "1" or s[y] == "2" or s[y] == "3" or s[y] == "4" or s[y] == "5" or s[y] == "6" or s[y] == "7" or s[y] == "8" or s[y] == "9":
            s[y] = ''
        y += 1

    s = "".join(s)
    w[x] = s
    x += 1





o = open("wzl.py", "w")
x = 0
p = 0
for i in range(len(w)):
    if x == (len(w) - 1):
        break
    y = 0
    o.write(f"{w[x]}1 = 1")
    o.write("\n")
    for i in range(len(w) - 1):
        y += 1

        if w[x] == w[y]:
            o.write(f"{w[x]}1 += 1  ")
            o.write("\n")
            del w[y]
            y -= 1



        if y == (len(w) - 1):
            o.write(f"print('{w[x]} = ', {w[x]}1)")
            o.write("\n")
            del w[x]
            x -= 1

    print(w)
    x += 1

o.close()
os.system("python wzl.py")
```

It opens the other file and writes this:

```
sitting1 = 1
print('sitting = ', sitting1)
in1 = 1
in1 += 1  
print('in = ', in1)
the1 = 1
the1 += 1  
print('the = ', the1)
sun1 = 1
print('sun = ', sun1)
away1 = 1
print('away = ', away1)
from1 = 1
print('from = ', from1)
everyone1 = 1
print('everyone = ', everyone1)
who1 = 1
print('who = ', who1)
had1 = 1
print('had = ', had1)
done1 = 1
print('done = ', done1)
him1 = 1
print('him = ', him1)
harm1 = 1
print('harm = ', harm1)
```

Now, all I need is for the code to go through every variable and print the first 10 from biggest to smallest, how do I do that? I think i can do it with class but i don't know how to use it.

Also if you find some way I can improve my code, please note.

Input example:
'Sitting in the sun, away from everyone who had done him harm in the past.'

Output example:

```
the: 6
he: 5
of: 2
she: 1
```

Comment: If you could add sample input and output that would be helpful to understand what you are trying to solve. Can you  please add more information and edit the original question?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use built-in [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module to do this work for you. Why reinvent the wheel when there is a builtin implementation

```py
from collections import Counter as Co
listofwords = 'Hi Hi a a a for be a hi hi hlo hlo'
print(Co(listofwords.split()))
#Counter({'a': 4, 'Hi': 2, 'hi': 2, 'hlo': 2, 'for': 1, 'be': 1})

# if you want to find the 2 most common words
print(a.most_common(2)) 
#[('a', 4), ('Hi', 2)]
```

> here is an article if you want to [read](https://realpython.com/python-counter/) about it